# Struts 1.2 with RESTful webservice

Tags: rest, java-7, struts-1

I'm working on a legacy application developed in Struts 1.2 and there is a need to develop a RESTful webservice for a client with JSON response. I have been searching for an example to achieve the same but could not find any. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have an Action Servlet fetching the result that is converted into a plain JSON String object and set in request attribute. The mapping forward redirect to a blank jsp page having contentType set to application/json, which just prints the request attribute. Not truely RESTful but it worked just fine.